# Search and replacing a string on specific file extensions

Tags: bash, string

I have this bash:

```
  replace="s/AAAA/BBBB/g";
  find myDirectory/. -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i $replace;
```

that will recursively scan `myDirectory` tree and replace all occurrences of `AAAA` with `BBBB` on the files there.

But I want to limit this to happen on files of specific extensions, for example, `.txt`, `.read`, `.po`

How do I impose this limit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `-name` option for find to restrict matches based on filename.

```
find myDirectory/. -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "$replace"
```

For multiple extensions, you can use `-o` (or) and group them with `()`.

```
find myDirectory/. -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.read' \) -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "$replace"
```

Another improvement that can be made is using `-exec` instead of `xargs`. This is more portable and eliminates a subshell.

```
find myDirectory/. -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i "$replace" {} +
```

Comment: 2nd option working for me... thanks!!!

Comment: For anyone googling, to run the last line in this answer without a variable, here is an example that recursively finds all txt files with foo and replaces with bar. Include the plus sign at the end:

 `find ./ -type f -name '*.txt' -readable -writable -exec sed -i "s/foo/bar/g" {} +`

Answer (score 4):

Add these settings to your `.bashrc`:

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
```

`extglob` turns on some additional [patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching-1), including the `@(…)` construct for disjunction. `globstar` turns on `**/` which traverses directories recursively.

Then you don't need to use `find`:

```
sed -i "$replace" mydirectory/**/*.@(txt|read|po)
```

In zsh, you don't need any special option, just run

```
sed -i $replace mydirectory/**/*.(txt|read|po)
```

If you have a lot of files, you may see a message like “command line length limit exceeded”. But the limit is very high on modern Linux systems, you're unlikely to encounter it.

Comment: I upvoted the question because I appreciate the globbing, but it seems overkill to ask someone to modify one's `.bashrc` for a single command. Why not just set it before the command, and optionally reset afterwards? If the user wants the setting permanently, that would be a separate issue.

Comment: Also, is `extglob` really necessary? Can't the same be accomplished with standard brace expansion, ie. `{txt,read,po}`instead of `@(txt|read|po)`?

Comment: @user1404316 Braces only work if there is at least one file with each extension. Otherwise the corresponding glob pattern will remain unchanged. E.g. if the current directory contains `hello.world`, `foo.txt`, `bar.txt`, `messages.po` only, then `cat *.(txt|read|po)` is equivalent to `cat messages.po bar.txt foo.txt` (single glob pattern, expands in lexicographic order) while `cat *.{txt,read,po}` expands to `cat bar.txt foo.txt *.read messages.po` and cat will complain that there is no file called `*.read`.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this successfully -- to replace occurence of DBA with AOS

```
sed -i -E "s/DBA/AOS/g" *.sh
```

Comment: The question says recursively.

Comment: Note that as you forgot the `--` or don't use a `./` prefix for the glob, with the GNU implementation of `sed`, that introduces a command injection vulnerability. Try after `mkdir -p s/DBA/AOS; echo > s/DBA/AOS/g; touch './-es:^:uname>\&2:e;#.sh'` for instance.