# Search and replacing a string on specific file extensions with the folder name

Tags: bash, find, directory, string, replace

I want to find a string ("AAA") in an specific file extension ("*.txt") inside a directory tree (../MyParentFolder), and replace it with the subfolder name (MySubfolder). I know a similar question is asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60485/search-and-replacing-a-string-on-specific-file-extensions) but I cannot make the jump to replacing with the subfolder name.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some examples. Show us the directory structure and some files and show us how you want the files to change. As it stands, it isn't clear if you want to replace al cases of `AAA` with `MySubfolder` or if `MySubfolder` should be the name of the directory containing each file. Also, please tell us what operating system you are using so we know what tools are available. Finally, also clarify if you want to match substrings. Should `abcAAAbca` become `abcMySubfolderbca` or should we only match cases where the `AAA` is found as a single word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the third example (with `exec`) from the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60489/97255) to [Search and replacing a string on specific file extensions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60485/97255):

```
find myDirectory/. -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i "$replace" {} +
```

First, set the `$replace` like so:

```
replace='s/AAA/MySubfolder/'
```

Then run the `find` command.

---

Note: You may find that you need to `export` the `replace`, as you are starting *another* process with the `find` command:

```
export replace='s/AAA/MySubfolder/'
```

Also, if there is more than one occurrence of "AAA" on any one line, and you wish to replace all of them, then you will need to make the substitution *global*, like so

```
s/AAA/MySubfolder/g
```

Comment: Alternatively, just read [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60485/search-and-replacing-a-string-on-specific-file-extensions#comment713150_60489)

Comment: You don't need to export the variable. The `$replace` shell variable is just expanded by the shell before invoking the `find` command. There's not command in their that will be querying the `replace` environment variable. Using a variable has little benefit here.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep` or compatible, you could do something like:

```
grep -rlZ --include='*.txt' AAA ../MySubfolder |
   perl -MFile::Basename -pi -e '
     BEGIN {local $/ = "\0"; @ARGV = <STDIN>}
     if ($. == 1) {
       $replacement = basename dirname $ARGV;
     }
     s/AAA/$replacement/g;
     close ARGV if eof' ''
```

Where `grep` finds the `txt` files that contain `AAA` at least once, and `perl` does the `i`n-place editing, extracting the folder name from the file name to make up the replacement for `AAA` upon reading the `1`<sup>st</sup> line of each file.

So `AAA` will be replaced with `MySubfolder` in `../MySubfolder/a.txt` and with `foo` in `../MySubfolder/foo/b.txt`.

If you want to replace `AAA` with `MySubfolder` always, then it's just:

```
grep -rlZ --include='*.txt' AAA ../MySubfolder |
  xargs -r0 perl -pi -e 's/AAA/MySubfolder/g'
```

(assuming GNU `xargs` or compatible).

GNU `sed` also supports `-i` à la `perl` for in-place editing, so you could use it instead of `perl` there for such a simple replacement:

```
grep -rlZ --include='*.txt' AAA ../MySubfolder |
  xargs -r0 sed -i 's/AAA/MySubfolder/g'
```